# CMake imported target found when configuring but generated build.make says target-NOTFOUND

Tags: cmake

I have a simple shared library `libfool2.so` with installed header `fool2.h` which are not from a CMake project. My project `my_temp1` depends on `fool2` so I write a `FindFool2.cmake` to make an imported target:

```
find_path(Fool2_INCLUDE_DIR fool2.h PATH_SUFFIXES fool2)
find_library(Fool2_LIB fool2)
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(Fool2
    REQUIRED_VARS Fool2_INCLUDE_DIR Fool2_LIB
)

if(Fool2_FOUND AND NOT TARGET Fool2::Fool2)
    add_library(Fool2::Fool2 SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(Fool2::Fool2 PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${Fool2_INCLUDE_DIR}"
        INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "${Fool2_LIB}"
    )
endif()
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` for `my_temp1` project is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(my_temp1)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake/cmake_modules) 
# FindFool2.cmake is in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake/cmake_modules

find_package(Fool2 REQUIRED)

if (TARGET Fool2::Fool2)
    message(STATUS "target found")
endif()

add_executable(my_temp1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_temp1 Fool2::Fool2)
```

Now

```
$ tree ../__install
../__install/
├── include
│   └── fool2
│       ├── fool2.h
│       └── version.h
└── lib
    └── libfool2.so
$ tree .
.
├── cmake
│   └── cmake_modules
│       └── FindFool2.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
$ cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../__install
# some output omitted
-- target found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /OMITTED/my_temp1/_builds
$ cmake --build _builds
CMakeFiles/my_temp1.dir/build.make:82: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/my_temp1.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_temp1.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
$ head -n 85 _builds/CMakeFiles/my_temp1.dir/build.make | tail -n 10

# External object files for target my_temp1
my_temp1_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS =

my_temp1: CMakeFiles/my_temp1.dir/main.cpp.o
my_temp1: CMakeFiles/my_temp1.dir/build.make
my_temp1: Fool2::Fool2-NOTFOUND
my_temp1: CMakeFiles/my_temp1.dir/link.txt
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=/OMITTED/my_temp1/_builds/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_2) "Linking CXX executable my_temp1"
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/my_temp1.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
```

The command `$ cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../__install` finds `fool2` because find_* commands searches in the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` as well.
But why is there weird output `my_temp1: Fool2::Fool2-NOTFOUND` in build.make?

CMake version is 3.11.3

Comment: For *IMPORTED* library target value `-NOTFOUND` corresponds to absent *IMPORTED_LOCATION* property. And you don't set that property.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Thanks and your answer is correct. Feel free to post it in an answer.

Comment: I confused the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` with `IMPORTED_LOCATION`. And there's the other question explaining the difference after you give me a pointer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648375/what-are-the-differences-between-imported-target-and-interface-libraries?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For *IMPORTED* library target value `-NOTFOUND` corresponds to absent [IMPORTED_LOCATION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) property, corresponded to the library's path. You need to set that property for correctly work with *IMPORTED* target.

---

If you want CMake target to be a placeholder just for link with other libraries, use *INTERFACE* library target instead: such library target doesn't have library location.